# i don't know what's wrong it gives me Manifest is not valid JSON. Line: 1, column: 1, Unexpected token what do i do

Tags: json, sublimetext3

i am running it on sublime text 3 it is for a project that i am working on its a chrome extension, I have searched a bit on youtube but i don't know what to do.

```
{
    "manifest_version" : 2,
    "name": "DJ_Khaled",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "This is a test extension",
    "browser_action": {
        "defualt_icon": "icon.png"
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverlow. Can You take the time to rewrite properly your question and please read the FAQ.

Comment: For your problem, your json is valid here. Not well naming but valid. You can use a linter for this. http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: when i try to upload it to chrome it doesn't work

Comment: Did you try the linter?

Comment: and when i upload it, it says Manifest is not valid JSON. Line: 11, column: 3, Trailing comma not allowed.
and sry for the question it's my first time

Comment: yes i did try the linter it approved it

Comment: thank you aloisdg i fixed it thank you for your help

Comment: Since it fix the problem, I will an answer. hope it can help someone else too.

Comment: This is [how you valid an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

When you have a trouble like the best way to fix it is to copy/paste it in a linter.

> Generically, lint or a linter is any tool that flags suspicious usage in software written in any computer language.

You can find a lot of the online. For you problem, try with [JsonLint.com](http://jsonlint.com/).

Since your are using SublimeText, you can use a [plugin](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/JSONLint) for this purpose too.

[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software))